# .bash_profile does not display echo information after update

Tags: unix, environment-variables, bash, railsapps

I am setting up environment variables, and after saving in `.bash_profile`, I gave this command:

```
echo "$SENDGRID_USERNAME"
```

After doing this, `bash` returned a blank line, and went back to the prompt on the following line.
This made me wonder that something is there, but maybe bash is not showing it. Or is there something else involved?
Also, do I need to have a path variable in the `.bash_profile`? If I do, what should it be?

Answer (score 1):

After store new stuff into **.bash_profile**, you should run

```
source .bash_profile
```

after that changes will work, or you can login once more on your account.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Terminal > Preferences > replace Command complete path by "/bin/bash"
[image]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).